# How to submit ajax form in wordpress (getting error 400)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am building my personal website based on wordpress / woocomerce. I am currently working on a form that allows users to change their account information such as name, surname and much more. Everything seems to be working fine.

What I'm trying to do now is make the form work with ajax requests without the need to refresh the page. I think I am on the right track but I have some small difficulties.

Currently, when the form is submitted the page is not loaded, so I have reached the goal, however the ajax request generates the error 400 and I don't understand why.

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I am new to all of this.

My Form

```
<form name="Form" class="mts-edit-account" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> > 
  <!-- Fist & Last Name Field -->
  <div class="row name_surname">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_first_name">Nome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_last_name">Cognome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </div> 

    <!-- Save Settings -->
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
      <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva modifiche', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
            alert('This is data returned from the server ' + data);
        }, 'json');
    });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_action', 'save_account_details' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_action', 'save_account_details' );
function custom_action() {
    
    $response = array(
        'error' => false,
    );

    if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['error_message'] = 'Name is required';
        exit(json_encode($response));
    }

    exit(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: The second parameter to `add_action` is the callable - that must be the name of your PHP function in this case, so `custom_action`, not `save_account_details`. And the `action` parameter you send with your request, must match the hook name, that's the part coming after `wp_ajax_`/ `wp_ajax_nopriv_`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed it to this `wp_ajax_save_account_details` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_save_account_details`. Now I no longer get the error 400, however the data is not canghed when submit form. Is there something wrong with my example ?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you did not implement _anything_ in there yet, that would actually update anything in the database, you mean? All you did so far was populate `$response`, and then send that back to the client ...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In fact, I'm stuck here now, I don't know what the next step is, I guess I have to put the form fields inside the code present in functions.php. Would you be kind enough to give me an indication that I can rely on to be able to solve the problem myself?

Comment: You will have to process the submitted data now, and update whatever fields this relates to in your database ... Not sure how to give any more specific info at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution to submit data with the form using ajax request but I'm not sure. As I am a newbie I hope someone can correct or improve my answer below. Anyway, now the data is sent and saved correctly but I still have some problems which I list below.

1. After sending I get 302 (redirect) status
2. If one of the fields is empty the validate does not work, the form is submitted anyway, while an error message should appear.

**Context**:
I'm working with woocommerce, so my form belongs to the form-edit-account.php template. This allows users to change their account settings such as first name, last name and much more.

**Reference**:
I followed this tutorial which helped me tremendously - https://regularcoder.com/submit-form-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

**My Form**

```
<form name="Form" class="mts-edit-account" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> > 
  <!-- Fist & Last Name Field -->
  <div class="row name_surname">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_first_name">Nome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="t3" for="account_last_name">Cognome *</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </div> 

    <!-- Save Settings -->
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
      <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Salva modifiche', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Script Js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) { //form onsubmit ecent
        e.preventDefault(); // the preventDefault function stop default form action

    //Ajax function
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Form Inviato');
      }
    });

    });

});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
function save_account_details() {
  // A default response holder, which will have data for sending back to our js file
  $response = array(
    'error' => false,
  );

  // Example for creating an response with error information, to know in our js file
  // about the error and behave accordingly, like adding error message to the form with JS
  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['error_message'] = 'Email is required';

  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
    $response['status'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Email is required';
    }else{
    $response['status'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'success';
    }

    // Exit here, for not processing further because of the error
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
  }
  
  // ... Do some code here, like storing inputs to the database, but don't forget to properly sanitize input data!

  // Don't forget to exit at the end of processing
  exit(json_encode($response));
}
```